# Parsing XLM with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML product feed that I am parsing with `PHP` to load products into a `database.`

I need to get each element into an array of `$products = array()` such as:

```
$products[AttributeID] = value
```

This is what I have so far:

I am using simplexml and I have got most of it:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($CatalogFileName) or die("can't open file " . $CatalogFileName);

    foreach($xml->children() as $products) { 
        foreach($products->children() as $product) {
            $new_product = array();
            $new_product[sku] = "AS-" . $product->Name;
            foreach($product->Values->Value as $node) { 
                $node_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $node[AttributeID]);
                $new_product[$node_name] = $node[0];  **<--THIS IS NOT WORKING: $node[0] returns an array I only want the data in each attribute.**
            }
            foreach($product->AssetCrossReference as $node) { 
                $new_product[image] = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/images/items/fullsize/" . $node[AssetID] . ".jpg";
            }
            print_r($new_product); 
        }
    }
```

Here is an image of one product node: [XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3v3W.jpg)

Can someone provide me with a little help here?  I do a lot of PHP programming but this is the first time I am dealing with XML

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Have you tried to debug this piece of code? Does this library contain error? Some function returns unexpected values? Which values do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possbile solution is to use the [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to find the `<Value>` elements.
The `xpath` method will return an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

These [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) objects have an [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method which you can use to access the 'AttributeID' attribute.

I hope this example can help you:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($CatalogFileName) or die("can't open file " . $CatalogFileName);

$productsArray = array();

foreach($xml->children() as $products) {
    foreach($products->children() as $product) {
        $new_product = array();
        $productId = (string)$product->attributes()->ID;
        $new_product['NAME'] = "AS-" . (string)$product->Name;

        // xpath will return an array of SimpleXMLElement objects
        $values = $product->Values->xpath('//Value');

        // use the attributes method to access the AttributeID
        foreach ($values as $node) {
            $attributeID = (string)$node->attributes()->AttributeID;
            $new_product[$attributeID] = trim((string)$node);
        }

        $new_product['AssetID'] = sprintf(
            "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/images/items/fullsize/%s.jpg",
            (string)$product->AssetCrossReference->attributes()->AssetID
        );

        // Add $new_product to $productsArray using the $productId as the array key
        $productsArray[$productId] = $new_product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That helped and I have the code working.

Comment: @BillJorgensen
Nice! :-) If this answer helped you solve your problem you can always consider to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Sure I will be glad to, how do I do that?